# Microsoft Graph API - Null Root for a Drive

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I can get Root from my personal drive as follows.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(myAuthProvider);
DriveItem folder = await graphClient.Drive.Root.Request().Expand(expandValue).GetAsync();
```

I can fetch groups and obtain drives for each group as follows.

```
var groups = await graphClient.Groups.Request().GetAsync();
var drives = await graphClient.Groups[groups.First().Id].Drives.Request().GetAsync();
```

However, when I request a Root for any of these drives, it is always Null.

```
DriveItem folder = drives.First().Root;
```

Notably, Drive itself looks valid: name, URL and all other fields are valid. Drive is definitely not empty. It contains a lot of folders and files. How can I get items from this drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Root` is not a part of a response

```
var drives = await graphClient.Groups[groups.First().Id].Drives.Request().GetAsync();
```

Use `Expand` to include `Root` into the response

```
var drives = await graphClient.Groups[groups.First().Id].Drives
                   .Request()
                   .Expand(x => x.Root).GetAsync();
```

or

```
var drives = await graphClient.Groups[groups.First().Id].Drives
                   .Request()
                   .Expand("root").GetAsync();
```

For SDK v5 the code is:

```
var drives = await graphClient.Groups[groups.First().Id].Drives
                   .GetAsync(conf=>
                   {
                       conf.QueryParameters.Expand = new[] { "root" };
                   });
```

Comment: What's would be the answer for the updated version of the SDK? In `Microsoft Graph nuget v.5.17.0`  'Drive' does not contain properties or methods I can find that would translate to `Request().Expand()`..., nor the code in this official tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/msgraph-dotnet-core-manage-files/5-display-user-files) with `_graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request()`

Comment: @Derptastic Updated with code for sdk v5